# Android Common XML Parser

Tags: android, web-services, xml-parsing, android-xml

I want a common Parser which parse any type of XMl response.
At present I am using XmlPullParser.. in which I am passing xmlresponse from webservice and checking XmlPullParser.START_TAG and store data in the Beans Object accordingly..

for that I am creating one bean, one parser for each of the webservice I am parsing..

I've gone through one common parser over iOS App which input all the start tag as array to any webservice and storing data in key-value pair, and gives one object which contains all the data.. so no need of creating Bean and Parser separately..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Common class for XML is the nice idea. I have created a demo to make a common XML parser class.

To create a common class there can be many ways,It depends on your requirement. Some persons want to get the KeyValuePair like you are referencing in your question or some wants different ways.

I have create one XML parser class which will parse the xml file and will return object. This object can have multiple childs.

You can get the code from [this blog](http://dharmendra4android.blogspot.in/2012/04/common-xml-parser-for-all-type-of-xml.html).

Hope this will help everyone.

Comment: Mind blowing efforts.. !! Thanks Dharmendra !

Comment: hi @Dharmendra , I am getting a blank exception while calling display(xmlObject); it gives blank values.